# Add Exemplars to Metrics

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I'm having trouble figuring out how to append exemplars to my metrics.
my code is in python and i'm using prometheus-client library. i have my code instrumented for metrics but i still haven't been able to integrate data as exemplars to it.

my ultimate goal is to visualize my trace data as exemplars on my metrics panel in grafana dashboards.

In my application i create a simple counter that keeps track of the number of http requests. I add a few labels to that counter.
I can see the metrics prometheus pulls from the app and i can also visualize them on grafana but i can't find the way to append the trace data as an exemplar and also visualize it (yes i'm using grafana 8 and it supports exemplars)

this is my code for instrumentation using a counter

```
tasks_counter = Counter(
    name='outgoing_x_http_requests',
    documentation='counter for http requests from server x',
    labelnames=['status_code', 'method', 'path']
)

def send_X():
    // send request to server ...
    // response_object = returned values from server

    // my counter .. also adding labels to it
    tasks_counter.labels(
        status_code="some integer",
        method="some method",
        path="some path",
    ).inc(1)
```

i tried adding the trace id and span id as labels to the counter but it doesn't work. It's not how you create exemplars because they're not popping on my metrics graph ... what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There's an example (using Counter) here:

https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/pull/669/commits/fb35c5fdc0312cad8c9313a625e4f00a91d77fbd

But the PR is not yet merged.